# Dismiss Popover segue in the attached viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a storyboard with a `UIViewController` called `EntryViewController` that uses a popover segue to another `UIViewController` called `PopoverViewController`. Everything works perfectly on this front  but inside my `PopoverViewController` I created a `UIButton` to dismiss the popover but no matter what I do, I cannot get it to work and all tutorials online show users created the popover programmatically.

I've tried the following:

```
- (IBAction)dismissPopover:(id)sender {
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  //[self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to NSLog or debug inside your "dismissPopover" to ensure you're UIButton click event is triggering this?

Comment: Yes the dismissPopover is being executed. I've verified that with NSLog.

Comment: If anybody needs more information to help debug this I can get you any information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dismiss the popover by tapping area outside of the popover. In your PopoverViewController define a property that hold a reference to the segue's popOverController. In your root controller's prepareForSegue method, set the above mentioned property. Then you can use the property to dismiss the PopoverViewController.

In your PopoverViewController.h file define a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popOverController;

- (IBAction)dismissPopover:(id)sender {
   [self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

In your EntryViewController's prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"ShowPopOver"]) {
        if( [segue isKindOfClass: [UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]] ){
        PopOverViewController *controller = (PopOverViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.popOverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
    }
}
```

You can also download the [sample example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrbsqcrbj0gui20/DismissPopViewController.zip?dl=0)